# Recursive Bucket Sort (Java)

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, bucket-sort

So I have done a Bucket Sort algorithm that works just fine, but now I'm being asked to do it recursively. The Bucket Sort itself is something along the lines of:

```
public static void bucketSort(int[] arr, int max) {
      int[] bucket = new int[max + 1];
 
      for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         bucket[arr[i]]++;
      }
 
      int x = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < bucket.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < bucket[i]; j++) {
            arr[x++] = i;
         }
      }
   }
```

So my question would be, how to make this same algorithm but recursively?
Note: I'm coding in Java using IntelliJ, but feel free to explain in other languages if you prefer it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need to initialize all `bucket` indices with `0`; `new int[max + 1]` already does that.

Comment: @akuzminykh noted and edited, thanks!

Comment: Try these practice exercises for recursion if you haven't done much recursion before: https://codingbat.com/java/Recursion-1, to help you get into the right mindset.  If you're still stuck, show us what code you have so far for a recursive version and we'll see what we can do to help :)

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot for sharing the resources!

Comment: Isn't that a Counting Sort instead of a Bucket Sort?